# logging module using conf file not Working

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to config the logger using logging.conf file but I am getting error,
In Code I am trying to replace the file path in conf file with dynamic path includes timestamp folder
Following is my code

python module to configure the log -

```
class LogHandler:
    logger = None

    def __init__(self,file_path):
        conf_path = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())+"\\config\\log_config.conf"

        #Setting the log file path to configuration file
        with open(conf_path,'r') as file:
            content = file.readlines()
            file_path = file_path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
            print(file_path)
            for line_no in range(len(content)):
                if re.search("args=\('.*',", content[line_no]):
                    content[line_no] = "args=('" + file_path + "','a')\n"
                    break
        file.close()

        with open(conf_path,'w') as file:
            file.write(''.join(content))
        file.close()

        logging.config.fileConfig(conf_path)

        LogHandler.logger = logging.getLogger("root")

        LogHandler.logger.info("Testing")

    @staticmethod
    def getLogger():
        return LogHandler.logger
```

logging.conf module for configuration -

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=sampleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=sampleFormatter
args=('C:\\Users\\vipin\\PycharmProjects\\PythonBehaveFramework\\output\\201912100840\\output.log','a')

[formatter_sampleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s : %(lineno)s   -  %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vipin/PycharmProjects/PythonBehaveFramework/Features/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    LogHandler.getInstance("C:\\Users\\vipin\\PycharmProjects\\PythonBehaveFramework\\output\\output.log")
  File "C:\Users\vipin\PycharmProjects\PythonBehaveFramework\src\framework\LogHandler.py", line 28, in getInstance
    LogHandler(filename)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\PycharmProjects\PythonBehaveFramework\src\framework\LogHandler.py", line 50, in __init__
    logging.config.fileConfig(conf_path)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "C:\Users\vipin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\logging\config.py", line 148, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config for your `handler_consoleHandler` is inconsistent.

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
<snip>
args=('C:\\Users\\vipin\\PycharmProjects\\PythonBehaveFramework\\output\\201912100840\\output.log','a')
```

`fileConfig` creates a [`StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) instance, based on the `class` you specify. This class accepts one positional argument (other than `self`) upon instantiation.

```
class logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
```

The `args` you specify belong to a [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) resp. a subclass thereof, i.e. specify a log file path and mode.
This passes two positional arguments to the `StreamHandler` initializer, causing the TypeError.

If you want to log to a file, change to class of your handler to `FileHandler` or any of its derivatives.
If you indeed want to log to the console, either remove the `args` completely to stick with the default stderr or specify whichever other stream you desire, e.g. `args=(sys.stdout,)` of you want the handler to log to stdout instead.